# Make main JFrame not visible while splash screen is visible

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

I have this createAndShowGui() class that calls a splash screen from another method and creates a JFrame that is used for the main application.  I have been trying to figure out how to make the JFrame hidden while the splash screen is visible.

I tried using an

```
if (splash.isVisible()){
    frame.setVisible(false)
}
else { frame.setVisible(true)
}
```

This doesnt work.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?

```
private static void createAndShowGui() {
    DrawPanelMain mainPanel = new DrawPanelMain();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("RF Connection Panel " + version);
    SwingMenu mainBar = new SwingMenu();
    Splash splash = new Splash("C:\\Users\\Rob\\splashscreen.gif", frame, 8000);
    splash.setVisible(true);

    frame.setJMenuBar(mainBar);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Splash.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

/*
 * This class creates a splash screen that is displayed when the program is run.  It includes thread management,
 * mouse adapter, and runs with a JWindow on top of the JFrame for the overall application.
 */
public class Splash extends JWindow {
    public Splash(String filename, Frame f, int waitTime) {
        super(f);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(filename));
        getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Dimension labelSize = label.getPreferredSize();
        setLocation(screenSize.width / 2 - (labelSize.width / 2), screenSize.height / 2 - (labelSize.height / 2));

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                setVisible(false);
                dispose();
            }
        });

        final int pause = waitTime;
        final Runnable closerRunner = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                setVisible(false);
                dispose();
            }
        };

        Runnable waitRunner = new Runnable() {
            public void run(){

            try {
                Thread.sleep(pause);
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(closerRunner);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    };

        setVisible(true);
        Thread splashThread = new Thread(waitRunner, "SplashThread");
        splashThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me a bit about your Splash class?

Comment: @bodidely splash (string imagename, frame name, int  time until sleep)

Comment: @feltersnach your question is very unclear ..can you show relavant code of splach class

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Idea 2

Since you've passed the frame to the Splash object, you can simply make it visible in the same methods you hide your Splash.

First, add an instance variable for the frame so all methods can access it and assign it to the constructor parameter.

```
public class Splash extends JWindow {
    private JFrame frame;
    public Splash(String filename, Frame f, int waitTime) {
       super(f);
       this.frame = f;
```

Then, in your methods to hide the Splash screen, hide your frame.

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        setVisible(false);
        this.frame.setVisible(true); 
        dispose();
       }
   });
```

And finally..

```
 final Runnable closerRunner = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         setVisible(false);
         this.frame.setVisible(true);
         dispose();
     }
 };
```

Comment: Updating with another idea

Comment: This is a very close solution.  I will work on it again tomorrow.  Thanks.